# Should I edit a poorly constructed question, or just start a new one and delete the old one?

Tags: discussion

I didn't put enough of effort into clarifying a somewhat argumentative question a few months back, and the result was a poorly rated question with a lot of answers that didn't really speak to the nuance of my question.

I'm thinking about revisiting this, so I'd like to know the etiquette. My gut says it'll be easier and more productive to make a new question without the baggage, but I'm not sure how to handle the old question. But I just want to double check that I'm not violating a community norm by doing so.

Comment: As Alex said, the presence of so many answers makes that tough, since you'd be changing the context of it and invalidating them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd make a new question with a clearly worded answer.

Then revisit your old question and either comment that "Hey everyone I asked a related question here: *link*" or "I've opened this question (*link*) and I think this old question should be closed because of XYZ.   I've voted to close.   Consider doing the same."